# GridView::FILTER_SELECT2 dont work

Tags: php, gridview, yii

I try to use SELECT2 as a filter for a column but it didn't render!

This is my code :

```php
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;
use yii\widgets\ListView;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\country;
?>
 <?php
echo GridView::widget([
'columns' => [  
        ['attribute' =>'id','filter'=>GridView::FILTER_SELECT2],
       'name'],
    'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
     'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'export'=>false,
        'pjax'=>true,
        'pjaxSettings'=>[
        'neverTimeout'=>true]

]);
   ?>
```

and than I get this result in browser:

[image: photo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `filterType` instead of `filter`.

```
['attribute' => 'id', 'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2]
```

Comment: thank you , you have right .. i just update the normal gridview to kartik gridview . in the first one its filter . but now It returned an Empty list box !! from where take this Select2 the data ?

Comment: Add `filter` key there and its value set as array of available options like mentioned [in the docs](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.10/framework/grid/DataColumn.php#L98)

Comment: great ! it's worked  , thank you . it's hier possible to use the normal Select2 pluginOptions or pluginEvents  for example I need to use    `'multiple'=>'true'` hier where I can added ?

Comment: You need to check this in [documentation](http://demos.krajee.com/grid)